# Generic class for SELECT in mysql leads to endless loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I began to write a generic class for SELECT queries that looks like this:

```
class DbQuery
{
    private $database;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $db_config = array(
            "type" => "mysql",
            "host" => "localhost",
            "port" => "3306",
            "charset" => "utf8",
            "db" => "dbname",
            "user" => "user",
            "password" => "topsecret"
        );

        $this->database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection($db_config);
    }

    public function Select($keys = array("*"), $table, $whereClauseArray = null, $orderValues = null, $orderDirection = null, $limitIndex = null, $limitLength = null)
    {
        $statement = "SELECT " . implode(',', $keys) . " FROM " . $table;
        if (!empty($whereClauseArray)) {
            $whereClauseString = " WHERE ";
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($whereClauseArray as $whereClause) {
                if ($i > 0) {
                    $whereClauseString .= " " . $whereClause['link'] . " ";
                }
                $whereClauseString .= $whereClause['key'] . " " . $whereClause['operand'] . " :" . $whereClause['key'] . "_" . $i;
                $i++;
            }
            $statement .= $whereClauseString;
        }
        if (!empty($orderValues)) {
            $orderClause = " ORDER BY ";
            foreach ($orderValues as $order) {
                $orderClause .= $order . ", ";
            }
            $orderClause = substr($orderClause, 0, -2);
            $statement .= $orderClause . " " . $orderDirection;
        }
        if ($limitIndex != null && $limitLength != null) {
            $statement .= " LIMIT " . $limitIndex . "," . $limitLength;
        }

        $query = $this->database->prepare($statement . ";");
        $file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/../db.log';
        $current = file_get_contents($file);
        $current .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()) . " => ";
        $current .= "Statement: " . $statement . "\n";
        file_put_contents($file, $current);
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($whereClauseArray as $whereClause) {
            $keystring = ":" . $whereClause['key'] . "_" . $j;
            $bindValue = trim(strip_tags($whereClause['value']));
            $query->bindValue($keystring, $bindValue);
            $file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/../db.log';
            $current = file_get_contents($file);
            $current .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()) . " => ";
            $current .= "BindValue: " . $keystring . " -> " . trim(strip_tags($whereClause['value'])) . "\n";
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
            $j++;
        }

        // $query->execute();

        if ($keys === "count(*)") {
            return $query->fetchColumn(0);
        } else {
            return $query->fetchAll();
        }
    }
}
```

I call the function like that:

```
$obj_artikel_startseite = new DbQuery();
$obj_artikel_startseite->Select(array("*"), "psartikel", array(array("link" => "AND", "key" => "status", "value" => "freigeschaltet", "operand" => "="), array("link" => "OR", "key" => "status", "value" => "reserviert", "operand" => "=")), array("id"), "DESC", 0, 3)) {
```

As long as I leave the execution commented, I get a proper output in my db.log file:

```
2022-10-23 19:35:51 => Statement: SELECT * FROM psartikel WHERE status = :status_0 OR status = :status_1 ORDER BY id DESC
2022-10-23 19:35:51 => BindValue: :status_0 -> freigeschaltet
2022-10-23 19:35:51 => BindValue: :status_1 -> reserviert
```

But when I try to execute the prepared statement with binded values, it leads to an endless loop. I don´t understand why.
Regards

Edit: Endless loop means the execution limit exceeds and the output in my log is about thousands, indentical entries...

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Atlas](http://atlasphp.io), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/),  or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: This has an alarming amount of unescaped string concatenation.

Comment: When you say "endless loop" do you mean "query takes too long"?

Comment: @Bill Karvin: Endless loop means the execution limit exceeds and the output in my log is about thousands, indentical entries...

Comment: This function doesn't look like a good idea. See [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)